# Sort object with custom date format

Tags: javascript, sorting

Help please me with sorting. 
I have to sort object with custom string date

```
var object = [{
  name: "something",
  date: "23.12.2016"
},
{
  name: "something2",
  date: "19.12.2016"
}]
```

how sort object like this? 
I already tried with sort function `return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);` but had nothing it doesn't work 
Thanks !

Comment: is the date padded with zero, eg `01.01.2017`?

Comment: yes it starts from 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the date and rearrange it as iso date and sort by string with `localeCompare`.

```js
var object = [{ name: "something", date: "23.12.2016" }, { name: "something2", date: "19.12.2016" }];

object.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a.date.split('.'),
        bb = b.date.split('.');
  
    return [aa[2], aa[1], aa[0]].join('-').localeCompare([bb[2], bb[1], bb[0]].join('-'));
});

console.log(object);
```

You could use as well `String#replace` for reordering the string.

```js
var object = [{ name: "something", date: "23.12.2016" }, { name: "something2", date: "19.12.2016" }];

object.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a.date.replace(/(..).(..).(....)/, '$3-$2-$1'),
        bb = b.date.replace(/(..).(..).(....)/, '$3-$2-$1');

    return aa.localeCompare(bb);
});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `Date.parse()` and `String.prototype.replace()` functions(to sort by ***timestamps***):

```js
var date_objects = [{ name: "something", date: "23.12.2016" }, { name: "something2", date: "19.12.2016" }];

date_objects.sort(function(a,b){
    return Date.parse(a.date.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})$/, '$3-$2-$1'))
            - Date.parse(b.date.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})$/, '$3-$2-$1'))
});

console.log(date_objects);
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, I tried a variation about [Nina Scholz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41505171/2932052), maybe it's faster, maybe not. I find reformatting the date quite obvious, but it's also time-consuming. In my version the duplicate indices are probably a problem, but [as you stated that the format is zero-padded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505020/sort-object-with-custom-date-format#comment70215487_41505020), this will work:

```js
var object = [{ name: "something", date: "23.12.2016" }, { name: "something2", date: "19.12.2016" }];

object.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.date[6] - b.date[6]) 
        || (a.date[7] - b.date[7])
        || (a.date[8] - b.date[8])
        || (a.date[9] - b.date[9])
        || (a.date[3] - b.date[3])
        || (a.date[4] - b.date[4])
        || (a.date[0] - b.date[0])
        || (a.date[1] - b.date[1]);
});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: nice idea, but you could use year, month and day together with slice.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the hint :) Is slicing cheap? Is the "bracketed" access cheap at all? (I'm used to it from C/C++)

Comment: @NinaScholz concerning using single chars (although it seems not to be portable): I spare parsing of multi-digit decimals integers from strings because all is of fixed size and all chars are. But well Javascript does a lot of parsing...